# Object instance is overwriting the other instance but I cant see why

Tags: c#, object, constructor, instances

I was wondering if you could look at my code and see where I have gone wrong. Basically, I have created an object of type "UserFile"(my own object type) and am creating 2 instances of it and within the constructor of that object, I am calling a static class method. All goes well for them except the second instance overwrites the first one after the object constructor is called. I have stepped through the program and am thoroughly confused. I get the feeling im missing something very obvious here.

**Here is the button on the form that creates the instances**

```
    private void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstFiles.CheckedItems.Count == 2)
        {
            file1 = new UserFile(((FileLocation)lstFiles.CheckedItems[0]).filePath);

            file2 = new UserFile(((FileLocation)lstFiles.CheckedItems[1]).filePath);
        }
    }
```

**Here is the UserFile class with constructor**

```
public class UserFile
{
    public Dictionary<int,Individual> fileIndividuals;
    public Dictionary<int, Family> fileFamilies;
    public Header fileHead;

    public UserFile(string _dir)
    {
        fileIndividuals = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
        fileFamilies = new Dictionary<int, Family>();
        fileHead = new Header();
        ReadFromFile.Read(_dir);
        fileIndividuals = ReadFromFile.individuals;
        fileFamilies = ReadFromFile.families;
        fileHead = ReadFromFile.head;
    }
}
```

**Here is the ReadFromFile method called by the UserFile class**

```
static class ReadFromFile
{
    public static string filename = "";

    public static Header head;
    public static Individual individual;
    public static Dictionary<int, Individual> individuals = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();

    public static Family family;
    public static Dictionary<int, Family> families = new Dictionary<int, Family>();

    public static GedcomRecordEnum currentRecord = GedcomRecordEnum.None;
    public static GedcomSubRecordEnum currentFirstLvlRecord = GedcomSubRecordEnum.None;
    public static GedcomSecondLevelEnum currentSecondLvlRecord = GedcomSecondLevelEnum.None;

    static public void Read(string fileName)
    {
        individuals.Clear();
        families.Clear();
        head = null;
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            filename = fileName;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
                Match m = Regex.Match(currentLine, "(?<index>[0-9]) (?<keyword>[A-Z_@0-9]+)(?: *)(?<detail>.*)");

                string debug = m.Groups["index"].ToString();

                switch (m.Groups["index"].ToString())
                {
                    case "0":
                        ProcessRootLevel(m.Groups["keyword"].ToString());
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        ProcessLevel1(m.Groups["keyword"].ToString(), m.Groups["detail"].ToString());
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        ProcessLevel2(m.Groups["keyword"].ToString(), m.Groups["detail"].ToString());
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        ProcessLevel3(m.Groups["keyword"].ToString(), m.Groups["detail"].ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following static properties on the `ReadFromFile` class, if I assume by "overwritten" you mean that both instances of `UserFile` point to the same data:

```
 public static Dictionary<int, Family> families = new Dictionary<int, Family>();
 public static Dictionary<int, Individual> individuals = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
 public static Header head;
```

The problem lies in the constructor of `UserFile` on the use of **static** properties.

```
    ReadFromFile.Read(_dir);
    fileIndividuals = ReadFromFile.individuals; // <-- Uh-oh!
    fileFamilies = ReadFromFile.families;       // <-- Uh-oh!
    fileHead = ReadFromFile.head;               // <-- Uh-oh!
```

What happens here  is the member variables `fileIndividuals`, `fileFamilies` and `fileHead` are set to a **reference** of the `individuals`, `families` and `head` properties on the static `ReadFromFile` class, **not a copy** (as they are classes and not value types). So the next time `ReadFromFile.Read()` is called the static properties on `ReadFromFile` are updated (overwritten), but the prior instance of `UserFile` just points to the *same* static properties, ergo `file1` and `file2` will have the same data.

So how would you fix this? Two options:

1. Make `ReadFromFile` and instance class, and not a static one. Construct a new instance in the `UserFile` constructor and don't use **any** static properties.
2. Make a copy of the data in `individuals`, `families` and `head` in the constructor of `UserFile`. "foreach" through each item, and copy it into a new dictionary.

---

Simple explanation:

When you do an assign (the = character in C#) if the object is a class, then the target is assigned a "pointer" (reference) to the right hand side. If it's a value type it's copied. Dictionary is a class, so you get a pointer and not a copy.

Illustration in code:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
     public static List<string> MyList = new List<string> 
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<string> myList1 = MyStaticClass.MyList; 
    List<string> myList2 = MyStaticClass.MyList; 

    myList1.Add("Hello");  // Add to first list
    myList2.Add("World");  // Add to second list 

    foreach(string item in myList1) // print all items in the second list
    {
         Console.WriteLine("List 1: " + item); 
    }

    foreach(string item in myList2) // print all items in the second list
    {
         Console.WriteLine("List 2: " + item); 
    }
}
```

The output of this will be:

```
List 1: Hello
List 1: World
List 2: Hello
List 2: World
```

But why? We only added 'World' to `myList2`. Well `myList1` and `myList2` **point** to the same thing. When we did `myList1 = MyStaticClass.MyList` we didn't get a **copy** of the item, just a  **reference** to it.

Comment: thank you but I was wondering if u can explain it in more basic terms please? i am considering the second option

Comment: Done :) You really want option #1 by the way.

Comment: I know but when I stopped the ReadFromFile class being static, nothing worked. Ive forgotten the reason I made it static now

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!!!!!!!!!! i had commented out the 3 lines in the UserFile constructor that were making things go "uh oh". Thanks!